# Problemas al consultar la base de datos con una lista desplegable Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, base-de-datos

Tengo una duda. tengo un formularios con dos campos uno es un `input` y el otro es un `select` al hacer la búsqueda de los dos campos no me trae nada. Aquí coloco mi consulta:

```
$titulo = $request->get(‘titulo’);
$provincia = $request->get(‘provincia’);
$empleos = Empleo::orderBy(‘id’,‘DESC’) ->where(‘titulo’,‘LIKE’,"%$titulo%") ->where(‘provincia’, ‘LIKE’, “%$provincia%”) ->paginate(5);
```

Aquí mi formulario:

```
{!! Form::open([‘route’ => ‘busquedaprincipal’, ‘method’=>‘GET’]) !!}
{!! Form::text(‘titulo’, null, [‘class’ => ‘form-control form-control-lg’, ‘placeholder’ => ‘Buscar’]); !!}
{!! Form::select(‘provincia’, [‘euskadi’ => ‘Euskadi’, ‘alava’ => ‘Alava’, ‘bizkaia’ => ‘Bizkaia’, ‘guipuzkoa’ => ‘Guipuzkoa’], null, [‘class’ => ‘custom-select form-control form-control-lg’, ‘placeholder’ => ‘¿Donde?’, ‘id’ => ‘provincia’]); !!}
{!! Form::submit(‘Buscar’, [‘class’ => ‘btn btn-primary btn-lg my-sm-3 boton border-0’]) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con esto:

Primero que nada imprime las variables para saber si estas recibiendo la información correcta, para eso utiliza:

```
dd($titulo,$provincia);
```

La forma correcta de recibir los elementos del formulario en el controlador es la siguiente:

```
$inputs = $request->input();
$titulo = $inputs['titulo'];
$provincia = $inputs['provincia'];
```

Ya con estas dos aclaraciones, no debe darte ningún inconveniente al momento de realizar la consulta.

**Nota: recuerda que los nombres con los que recibes los inputs deben ser los mismos nombres de los elementos del formulario**

```
$empleos = Empleo::orderBy('id','DESC')
->where('titulo','like','%'.$titulo.'%') 
->where('provincia','=', $provincia')
->get();
```

Comment: por favor explica tu respuesta, ya que al ser solo código se considera de baja calidad

Comment: Ya hice una actualización en la respuesta por favor verifica.